# converting coordinates from an iPhone to iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, touch, formula

I have an app that detects custom touch points on the iPhone.

Touch points are between 2 points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). This forms a block and any touch that lies within that block is considered as a touch.

Now I'd like optimise this app for the iPad, but there are hundreds of these blocks that I do not want to redo again.
Is there a formula/algorithm that can be applied to scale these coordinates?

Comment: Did you ever got this scaling formula?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a horrible design, but nonetheless:

Iphone has screen dimensions 320x480 - ipad has 768x1024.

You could multiply the touch coordinates by scale (0.416 for x and 0.468 for y) and then do the rest of calculations... this of course assumes that you just stretch your iphone content over ipad screen.

Comment: This doesn't work as it sounds! I have tried doing something similar for my requirements. Converting iPhone (X, Y, width, height) coordinates to iPad. I used,

       X = 768/310.0 * X;
       Y = 1024/420.0 * Y;
            
       width = 768/320.0 * width;
       height = 1024/460.0 * height;  but this doesn't work...there must be something else that also matters in this point conversion! By doesn't work, I mean Button doesn't appear on the correct place on iPad after conversation. It goes up or down position too much!!

Comment: you realize that in the example you gave, you use two **different** values for **both** width **and** height, and only one of those **4** values is the correct one? And did you take into account the sizes of status/navigation bars?

Comment: oh sorry..I pasted wrong one...actually for me those magic wrong formula working best! :-) Please read X = 768/320.0 * X; Y = 1024/480.0 * Y; width = 768/320.0 * width; height = 1024/480.0 * height; I do care of navigation bars...If you consider iPhone whole screen without any bars and same for iPad, then do you think these formulas are correct and there is no other factor should be considered in this conversion? I am not sure but there is difference in iPhone and iPad the way one (ratina??) pixel form, may be that affect it?